# Using branch from recompose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I am refactoring a stateless functional component to use `branch` and `renderComponent` from `recompose`.

The original component looks like this:

```
const Icon = props => {
  const { type, name } = props
  let res
  if (type === 'font') {
    return (<FontIcon name={name} />)
  } else if (type === 'svg') {
    res = (<SvgIcon glyph={name} />)
  }

  return res
}
```

The component with branch looks like this:

```
const isFont = props => {
  const { type } = props
  return type === 'font'
}

const FontIconHoC = renderComponent(FontIcon)
const SvgIconHoC = renderComponent(SvgIcon)

const Icon = branch(isFont, FontIconHoC, SvgIconHoC)

Icon.propTypes = {
  type: string,
  name: string
}

export default Icon
```

I try and render the component using:

```
<Icon name='crosshairs' type='font' />
```

The resulting error looks like this:

```
invariant.js:44Uncaught Error: Icon(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`branch` returns a HOC, which accepts a component and return a component, so `branch(...)` is a HOC and `branch(...)(...)` is a component.

In your case, because `Icon` is not a component but a HOC, so React can't render it. To fix it, you can move `SvgIcon` out from `branch`'s arguments and apply it to  the HOC returned by `branch(...)`, ex:

```
const Icon = branch(
  isFont,
  FontIconHoC,
  a => a
)(SvgIcon)
```

We apply an identity function (`a => a`) to the third argument of `branch`. You can think of the identity function is also a HOC, which basically just return the component it gets and does nothing more.

Because this pattern is used very often, so the third argument of `branch` is default to the identity function. As a result, we can omit it and make our code simpler:

```
const Icon = branch(
  isFont,
  FontIconHoC
)(SvgIcon)
```

I've created a jsfiddle for these code. You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wuct/ayt2rmjy/3/).

Answer (score -4):

You can also just use an if statement instead of branch.  Consider that you just had some difficulties doing what an if statement does.

Maybe time to reconsider that library ?

Comment: the objective of the question was to figure out how to use branch from the documentation. it is an exploratory work that I am doing for myself. While I agree that branch might have limited use, there are certain utilities from `recompose` such as `withHandlers` and `withReducer` that I am really excited about. It has really helped me when refactoring gigantic React components into smaller stateless ones.

Comment: I encourage you to consider using the patterns recompose encourages, without necessarily using the library itself

Comment: @BradfordMedeiros This is a terrible answer. Having difficulty with a library shouldn't mean you should reconsider the library. The point of recompose is to make code more readable and testable which it does.

Comment: There's being diplomatic, and then there's the idea of calling out the emperor for not wearing any clothes. Think about this --> the above is literally, literally an if statement.  And he asked on stack overflow how to use a wrapper, that is a freaking basic if statement.  Just look at the source:  https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/branch.js   Wow amazing way to write x ? y: z.  Very weak.